# why my lambda is not able to download file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to download a file and store in /tmp of lambda, in log i can only see first hey, why i am not able to see any catch error or any other logs.

In local it works pretty fine.

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

// const url =
//   'someurl';

function downloadfile(url) {
  console.log('hi')
  const req = https.get(url, function (res) {
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('testObject.obj');
    res.pipe(fileStream);

    fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('error writing to the stream');
      console.log(err);
    });

    fileStream.on('finish', function () {
      fileStream.close();
      console.log('done');
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('error downloading the file');
    console.log(err);
  });
}





exports.handler = async (event) => {
    downloadfile(
  'someurl'
);
   
};
```

Comment: Attach an error handler on your `writeStream` like writeStream.on('error', callback); There must be a problem with the write stream and your not catching the error on streams.

Comment: in local there is no error

Comment: It must be a path issue then have you added the error handler in Lambda? It can give you error details. Are you able to open file in local after download?

Comment: yes, i am able to view file in local. I have updated my code

Comment: After the initial Hi mesage, there are no logs.

Comment: I recommend you check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging.html). It seems the get handler is not getting called, it might be due to https not sure, but could be.

Comment: Is the Lambda Running at all? If not you might want to check the Lambda configuration what is the entrypoint!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write to `./`, the only directory accessible by lambdas is `./tmp`

[As per AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/execution-environment.html)

> There is also a local file system available at /tmp for all Lambda functions